# Simple Image Gallery: Change image size on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

got a little problem. I've searched Google for hours now without finding any solution. Does anyone know a way to create a simple image gallery. I need nothing special. This is the code:

```
<a href="images/bild3254.jpg"><img src="images/bild3254.jpg" width="30%" height="30%"></a>
<a href="images/bild3255.jpg"><img src="images/bild3255.jpg" width="30%" height="30%"></a>
<a href="images/bild3256.jpg"><img src="images/bild3256.jpg" width="30%" height="30%"></a>
```

As you can see: Very basic gallery for personal offline use only. Images are loading all at the same time. All images are simply scaled down by the browser itself.

So far everything is fine. Now my problem: I want a button to change the size of ALL images on that page (about 100) on a single link or button click. How?

That means: SMALL LARGE (buttons) for example. When clicking on Large, it changes to 70% of its original size, on Small back to 30%. Simple switching of sizes.

Not wanted:

- only one image at a time changing size
- images need to remain that large size until next reload
- hyperlinks to the original sizes remain usable

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script to change the sizes dynamically, but I should warn you that when using a percentage as the size it actually refers to the container, not the actual size of the image. So 70% will be 70% of the window.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var resizeImages = function(size) {
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].style.width = size;
    images[i].style.height = size;
  }
}
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'small') {
    resizeImages('30%');
  }
  if (e.target.id == 'big') {
    resizeImages('70%');
  }
  if (e.target.id == 'toggle') {
    if (images[0].style.width == '30%') {
      resizeImages('70%');
    } else {
      resizeImages('30%');
    }
  }
}, false);
```

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var resizeImages = function(size) {
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].style.width = size;
    images[i].style.height = size;
  }
}
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'small') {
    resizeImages('30%');
  }
  if (e.target.id == 'big') {
    resizeImages('70%');
  }
  if (e.target.id == 'toggle') {
    if (images[0].style.width == '30%') {
      resizeImages('70%');
    } else {
      resizeImages('30%');
    }
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="images/bild3254.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400/abstract" width="30%" height="30%">
</a>
<a href="images/bild3255.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400/business" width="30%" height="30%">
</a>
<a href="images/bild3256.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400/animals" width="30%" height="30%">
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="small">Small</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="big">Big</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="toggle">Toggle</a>
```

Comment: First off: THANK YOU! My god, I did a search for almost 3 hours, trying a lot of different scripts - and this one works perfectly fine! That is exactly what I was looking for:)

And about the percentage: Yes, that was intended as the website will be for offline use only on different resolutions (iMac, Macbook Air and Ultrawide Monitor). Works better than fixed sizes.